# Bulding property paths programatically with another class's selectors. How does this work?

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

I have a method I that takes a variable number of `@selector()` values and returns a proper NSString I found on this site a while back. This is useful when building property paths for me because I don't like the idea of using strings for this and like the idea of the compiler being able to check the values the path is built from. The method is:

```
+(NSString *)keyPathFromSelectors:(SEL)firstArg, ...
{
    NSMutableArray *keys = [NSMutableArray array];

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, firstArg);

    for (SEL arg = firstArg; arg != nil; arg = va_arg(args, SEL))
    {
        [keys addObject:NSStringFromSelector(arg)];
    }

    va_end(args);

    return [keys componentsJoinedByString:@"."];
}
```

This works beautifully but the question is: Why? If I have property on my current object named `person` and it has a `name` the path would be `person.name` obviously and the call to my method would look like:

```
+(NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingFoo
{
    return [NSSet setWithObject:[self keyPathFromSelectors:@selector(person), @selector(name),nil]];
}
```

The `name` selector is (should not) technically visible in my current class, it's in the `Person` class to which I have a reference so how am I accessing the correct `name` SEL object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selectors are do not carry the guarantee that the method actually exists on the object in question. You can get compiler warnings that a selector name doesn't exist anywhere, but you won't get assurance that it does exist on the object it will be used on. For example, this compiles:

```
[person performSelector: @selector(applicationDidBecomeActive:)]
```

Even though `applicationDidBecomeActive` exists on your app delegate and not `person`.

However! This kind of thing *is* possible through compiler macros. Look at the [libextobjc](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc) library which provides exactly the kind of selector/key path compile time checking you're looking for. This is what powers a lot of the keypath magic in ReactiveCocoa but it can also be used standalone.